# Grails Spring Security Redirect Loop

Tags: grails, spring-security

I've read several other issues regarding the redirect loop and Spring Security but none of them have solved my problem just yet. I've upgraded an app to Grails 2.4.3 and Spring Security 2.0-RC4. I have the following in Config.groovy

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.active = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.auth.forceHttps = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com.mypackage.User'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'com.mypackage.UserRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'com.mypackage.Role'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = "Annotation"
grails.plugin.springsecurity.voterNames = [
    'authenticatedVoter', 'organizationRoleVoter'
]
grails.plugin.springsecurity.useSecurityEventListener = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.handlerNames =
  ['rememberMeServices',
      'securityContextLogoutHandler',
      'securityEventListener']
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
  '/':                              ['permitAll'],
  '/index':                         ['permitAll'],
  '/index.gsp':                     ['permitAll'],
  '/assets/**':                     ['permitAll'],
  '/**/js/**':                      ['permitAll'],
  '/**/css/**':                     ['permitAll'],
  '/**/images/**':                  ['permitAll'],
  '/**/favicon.ico':                ['permitAll'],
  '/login/**':                      ['permitAll'],
  '/login.gsp':                     ['permitAll']
]
```

And I have this in my development block of Config.groovy

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.definition = [
        '/**':         'REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL'
    ]
```

When I visit my app at the following URL:

```
https://localhost:8443/a/login/auth
```

I get a redirect loop.

Comment: Have you tried adding `grails.plugin.springsecurity.debug.useFilter = true` to your configuration to see what the plugin is doing and why it might be caught in a loop?

Comment: Also adding `info 'grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.DebugFilter'` to your log4j configuration might be helpful as well.

Comment: I've added @Secured(['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY']) to my LoginController and things are better, but I'm not sure if that is really needed or not. Adding the additional logging doesn't really tell me anything I don't already know.

Comment: Ah, the reason for this is that in newer versions of the plugin everything is locked down by default. So you will need to allow access to the login controller. Sorry, I should have spotted that in your config. Glad you got it working.

Comment: But I thought this, '/login/**': ['permitAll'], should have solved the problem without needing the annotation in the controller.